# Python Shell showing errors while importing MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql

I connected Python with MySQLdb using MySQLConnector but now i am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import MySQLdb
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so
```

After installing using homebrew, i am getting the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so
 Expected in: flat namespace in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so
```

Comment: From your traceback you are using the OS X native python. I might suggest that you try homebrew python instead, I often had compatibility problems before I switched.

Comment: Please clarify in your question 'using MySQLConnector'. Tracebacks show you don't use MySQL Connector/Python. Are you really using MacOS X 10.6 as the egg says?

Comment: I installed MySQLConnector and i am using OS X 10.9 - I am so confused that i do not know what to do :s